# Sum Column if a Group Name is a certain Value

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a group in a matrix that lists a category. Under it, it lists all the subcategories.
So when the report runs it looks like this:

```
                 Category
        SubCat1  SubCat2  SubCat3
Row1
Row2
Row3
```

Before the report is is just
[Category]
[SubCategory] but it expands out once the query is ran.

What I need to do is sum the values for SubCat2. If it SubCat1 or SubCat3 the values should be excluded. Does anyone know the expression on how to do this?

Also does anyone know a good website to learn about all the different expressions.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the total for all rows, for SubCat2 only, to appear at the end of the tablix, then the simplest way would be to add a total row to the tablix and change the expression for the Hidden property for the Sum cell to be:

```
=(Fields!SubCategory.Value<>"SubCat2")
```